# Validating deserialised object with Postsharp Contracts

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, postsharp

[This is kind of an obvious question but I couldn't find anything about it - if someone could reference me, it'll be grand.]

In a **WebAPI project**:

```
public class MyObject
{
   [PostSharp.Patterns.Contract.Required]
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class MyController : ApiController
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]MyObject obj)
   {
      /// ...
   }
}
```

During compilation, I guess PostSharp's validations put themselves in the setter of the property, so when `obj` is deserialised from the request's body, its fields aren't validated.

So, what's the best/clean way to validate that object?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Balas wrote, there's no simple solution to trigger PostSharp's validations after deserializing an object, except implementing `OnDeserialized` method of `ISerializationCallback` interface. So I post an Aspect I wrote that deep copies public properties of objects one by one through reflection, and hence activating the validations in the setters.

```
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class ArgsValidationAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
    {
        public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
        {
            if (!method.GetParameters().Any(p => p.ParameterType.IsClass))
            {
                Message.Write(method, SeverityType.Error, "MY001", "Cannot apply HttpObjectValidationAspect to method '{0}'.", method);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


        public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args.Arguments)
            {
                try
                {
                    RecursiveCopyInstance(arg);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e.InnerException ?? e;
                }
            }

            base.OnInvoke(args);
        }

        private static object RecursiveCopyInstance(object origin)
        {
            var type = origin.GetType();
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                var val = prop.GetValue(origin);
                if (val != null && !prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && !prop.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
                {
                    val = RecursiveCopyInstance(val);
                }

                prop.SetValue(instance, val);
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no clean way to achieve such validation as it is presumed that once-serialized object is already valid.

In order to force the validation logic, one would need to use `ISerializationCallback` interface's `OnDeserialized` method, go through properties and forcibly set them to their current value in order to enforce validation.

This can be done by a PostSharp aspect, but it would be certainly non-trivial. Other possibility is to use reflection/expression trees to achieve the same.

If you think that this would be a nice feature of PostSharp, you can vote [PostSharp's UserVoice page](http://postsharp.uservoice.com).